# Primes in a certain sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Can a positive integer added to the integer obtained by reversing its digits (A056964 in the OEIS) be a prime infinitely often?

Comment: Maybe this article can be interesting for you: http://vixra.org/pdf/1701.0462v1.pdf.

Comment: It's probable.  But maybe not provable in the current state of the art.  See [OEIS sequence A072366](http://oeis.org/A072366)